Resource Obfuscation Not Applying to AAB's `res` Directory Despite R8 Configuration
I am trying to obfuscate the resources in an Android App Bundle (AAB), but I've encountered an issue where the resource names within the res directory are not being obfuscated, despite having R8 enabled for my project. When I build an APK, I can verify through Android Studio that the res directory contents are indeed obfuscated. However, upon building an AAB, the res directory appears untouched. How can I ensure that the resource names in the AAB are obfuscated as well?
Thanks
Here is my configuration:
buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        isShrinkResources = true
        isDebuggable = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        resValue("string", "app_name", "${project.extra["appName"]}")
    }
}


Renaming the entries in the res folder is not done by the resource shrinker or by R8, it is done in a different pass. Jake made a blog about it some time ago:
https://jakewharton.com/smaller-apks-with-resource-optimization/
For aab, they are probably not done by default
